# Problemas al insertar datos en base de datos mysql desde php

Tags: php, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin

Tengo los siguientes códigos php para realizar un formulario y después registrar o insertar estos datos en la base de datos el problema es que no inserta ningún dato.

Codigo del formulario se realiza la conexion a la tabla deseada que se encuentra en la base de datos y despues con un form se mandan los datos a registar.php:

```
<?php
   include("cn.php");
   $histclinic = "SELECT * FORM histclinic";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Consultorio Patricia's</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container-add">
       <h1 class="container__title">Historial clinico</h1>
       <form action="registrar.php" method="POST" class="container__form">
           <label for="" class="container__label">Nombre del paciente:</label>
           <input type="text" class="container__input" name="nom_pac">

           <label for="" class="container__label">Peso:</label>
           <input type="number" step="any" class="container__input" name="peso">

           <label for="" class="container__label">Talla:</label>
           <input type="number" class="container__input" name="talla">

           <label for="" class="container__label">Altura:</label>
           <input type="number" step="any" class="container__input" name="altura">

           <label for="" class="container__label">Temperatura:</label>
           <input type="number" class="container__input" name="temperatura">
           
           <label for="" class="container__label">Presion arterial:</label>
           <input type="text" class="container__input" name="presionart">

           <label for="" class="container__label">Pulso:</label>
           <input type="number" class="container__input" name="pulso">

           <br><br>
           <label for="" class="container__label">Prescripcion:</label>
           <br>
           <textarea name="prescripcion" id="" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
           <br><br>
           <label for="" class="container__label">Medicamentos:</label>
           <br>
           <textarea name="medicamentos" id="" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
           
           <br><br>
           <input class="container__submit" type="submit" value="Registrar">
       </form>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Codigo que inserta los datos en la Base de datos de nombre "registrar.php":

```
<?php
    include("cn.php");

    $id=1;
    $idpac=1;
    $nom_pac = $_POST["nom_pac"];
    $peso = $_POST["peso"];
    $talla = $_POST["talla"];
    $altura = $_POST["altura"];
    $temperatura = $_POST["temperatura"];
    $presionart = $_POST["presionart"];
    $pulso = $_POST["pulso"];
    $prescripcion = $_POST["prescripcion"];
    $medicamentos = $_POST["medicamentos"];

    $insertar = "INSERT INTO histclinic(ID,NOMBRE,IDPACIENTE,PESO,TALLA,ALTURA,TEMPERATURA,
                PRESIONART,PULSO,PRESCRIPCION,MEDICAMENTOS) VALUES (1,$nom_pac,1,$peso,$talla,$altura,
                $temperatura,$presionart,$pulso,$prescripcion,$medicamentos)";

?>
```

Código que hace la conexión con la base de datos de nombre "cn.php":

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "consultorio");
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    ?>
```

Base de datos creada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estructura de la tabla a la que quiero insertar los datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero, no indicas cual es tu problema, no se realiza la inserción?, es lo que puedo ver , falta la instrucción que ejecuta $insertar.

Comment: Al final de `registrar.php` tendrías que ejecutar la instrucción `INSERT` de este modo: **`$conexion->query($insertar);`** NOTA: He usado la sintaxis orientada a objetos porque es más clara. Aunque en tu conexión usas la sintaxis procedural,  te recomiendo que aprendas a usar la sintaxis orientada a objetos, no sólo por claridad, sino porque algunas funciones del estilo procedural son obsoletas. Por otro lado, deberías blindar tu código contra *Inyección SQL*.

Answer (score 0):

Al final de `registrar.php` tendrías que ejecutar la instrucción `INSERT` con el [método `query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) de este modo:

```
$conexion->query($insertar);
```

PERO antes debes corregir algunas cosas.

En la imagen se ve que la columna `ID` es auto-incremental, supongo que la finalidad de esa columna es usarla como llave primaria. Entonces no tiene sentido pasarle un valor fijo en la instrucción. Generalmente se pasa `NULL` como valor y el SGBD se encarga de asignar el valor auto-incrementado.

Por tanto, corrige la instrucción de este modo:

```
$insertar = "INSERT INTO histclinic(ID,NOMBRE,IDPACIENTE,PESO,TALLA,ALTURA,TEMPERATURA,
            PRESIONART,PULSO,PRESCRIPCION,MEDICAMENTOS) VALUES (NULL,$nom_pac,1,$peso,$talla,$altura,
            $temperatura,$presionart,$pulso,$prescripcion,$medicamentos)";

if ($conexion) {
    if ( $conexion->query($insertar) ) {
        $msg = "Filas insertadas: ".$conexion->affected_rows;
    } else {
        #Imprime mensajes de $conexion->error sólo para depurar
        $msg = "Hubo un error: ".$conexion->error;
    }
} else {
    $msg="No hay conexión. Revisa tus credenciales";
}
echo $msg;
```

**NOTAS:**

1. He usado la sintaxis orientada a objetos porque es más clara. Aunque en tu conexión usas la sintaxis procedural,  te recomiendo que aprendas a usar la sintaxis orientada a objetos, no sólo por claridad, sino porque algunas funciones del estilo procedural son obsoletas. De hecho [`mysqli_connect`  es la primera de la lista](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.mysqli.php). Migrar la conexión al estilo orientado a objetos es muy simple ([ver los ejemplos del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php)).
2. Por otro lado, deberías blindar tu código contra *Inyección SQL*.
3. Deberías controlar también que aquellas variables esenciales de la tabla no están vacías antes de ejecutar el insert.

Comment: Hola ya realice los cambios que me comentaste pero sigue sin insertar los datos en la tabla de la base de datos también ya cambie la conexión al servidor como me recomendaste.

Comment: @IrvingCardonaCamacho es que en tu código falta también manejo de errores. Revisa la respuesta editada, he escrito una versión con manejo de errores. Ahí podrás ver por qué falla la consulta. Si aún así no ves nada en pantalla puede haber algo que se te esté escapando en otro punto del programa. El ejemplo aquí basta para comprender que debes asegurarte del estado de cada cosa antes de usarla. Parece tedioso, pero si no programas de esta forma tendrás bloques de código mudo (como de hecho ocurre), el código no hace nada y no sabes por qué y aunque haga algo tampoco informa de lo que hizo.

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudo muchos que imprimiera que sucede ya quedo solucionado